# Appending div inside another div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an input box into a div and the following is my code:

```
document.getElementById('locations').appendChild('<div id="'+lname+'"><input placeholder="'enter please'" type="text" name="newbutton"/><br/><br/></div>');
```

I am not using `innerHTML+=` method because my previously created input boxes lost the text content while appending a new input box using that.

The above code appears to be not working for me. Is there any problem with the code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `innerHTML`. It doesn't eat the previous HTML. You've to fix an issue with the `placeholder` though.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is totally wrong: the `.appendChild()` method doesn't get a `string` as argument, it gets a `NodeElement`. So you should first create the elements, and then append them to the parent. The correct code would be:

```
var container = document.getElementById('locations'),
    children = document.createElement('div'),
    input = document.createElement('input');

children.id = lname;
input.placeholder = 'enter please';
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'newbutton';

children.appendChild(input);
container.appendChild(children);
```